# Spring and ExtJS Improvements for Cloud Computing

Tags: spring, extjs, cloud, erp

I'm thinking on create a ERP aplication for Cloud Computing using Spring, ExtJS (view) and PostGres (db). Then If you can, please take me some improvements to develope that aplication. Maybe what kind of considerations should i have?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spend a lot of thoughtful time designing your DB schema to make sure that the data demands are going to be scalable.  This applies to the overall framework of your application.  Connection/load testing should be part of your process early on to identify any part of your framework may need tweaking.